# web-browser addon and java applets?

Tags: java, javascript, applet, japplet, browser-addons

I have an online service which uses a java applet to perform client side task but the user must left open the webpage hosting the applet to let it work, my question is -

if I run this applet locally via an web-browser addon can the user close the webpage and the applet would continue to run in background ?

Also, will launching the applet locally still generate the initial launch security warning ?

Comment: *"Also, will launching the applet locally still generate the initial launch security warning ?"* What security warning exactly?  Quote the text or get a screen-shot.  Is it a warning in the browser page (like Chrome puts), or a free-floating warning from the browser, Java ..or parts unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I run this applet locally via an web-browser addon can the user close the webpage and the applet would continue to run in background ?

No.  When a page is closed, the browser/JRE will call the `close()` then `stop()` methods.
When it suits them, the JVM will be stopped.  That might occur 30-60 seconds after the last applet (in that JVM) stops.